# Как уменьшить разрешение изображения?

Tags: php, laravel

***контроллер***

```
   $target_file_name = public_path().'/upload/'.Str::random(10);
        $type = $_FILES["image2"]["type"];
        $type = stristr($type, '/');
        $type = substr($type, 1);
        $response = array();
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_name.'.'.$type);
        $user->ydostak =basename($request=$target_file_name.'.'.$type );
```

***форма если нужно***

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="ydostak" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Фото удостоверение с двух сторон') }}</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="file" name="image2" >
                                </div>
                        </div>
```

> Мне нужно чтобы прежде чем загрузилась изображение в upload  было
>   уменьше в разрешение наприер поьзователь загрузил изображение в 1280
>   на 1280  а мой контролер его уменьшает допустим 300 на 300  и
>   загружалось в upload

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805497/php-resize-image-on-upload

Comment: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-resize-image-before-upload-exampleexample.html